# mysql: deleted performance_schema, is it a problem?

Tags: mysql, performance

Been following this tutorial
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927690/howto-clean-a-mysql-innodb-storage-engine/4056261#comment14041132_4056261

in the process I deleted performance_schema along with the other dbs.

I dont see it reappear after reimporting dbs. Is it ok if I dont have performance schema?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MySQL Performance Schema is a feature for monitoring MySQL Server execution at a low level. The Performance Schema is available as of MySQL 5.5.3.

From MySQL Manual there are some of the features of the **performance_schema** database.

> The Performance Schema provides a way to inspect internal execution of
>   the server at runtime. It is implemented using the PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA
>   storage engine and the performance_schema database. The Performance
>   Schema focuses primarily on performance data. This differs from
>   INFORMATION_SCHEMA, which serves for inspection of metadata.
>
> The Performance Schema monitors server events. An “event” is anything
>   the server does that takes time and has been instrumented so that
>   timing information can be collected. In general, an event could be a
>   function call, a wait for the operating system, a stage of an SQL
>   statement execution such as parsing or sorting, or an entire statement
>   or group of statements. Currently, event collection provides access to
>   information about synchronization calls (such as for mutexes) file and
>   table I/O, table locks, and so forth for the server and for several
>   storage engines
>
> Performance Schema events are distinct from events written to the
>   server's binary log (which describe data modifications) and Event
>   Scheduler events (which are a type of stored program).

For detailed information look this Link [Performance Schema.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/performance-schema.html)

Comment: Ok thanks, found how to recreate it here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/performance-schema-quick-start.html